# cassandra trigger on [copy from MAXBATCHSIZE]

Tags: cassandra, triggers

when I'm trying to run the following CQL, I found that the canssandra trigger is not ran by one record, but by one batch.

```
COPY XXX_Table FROM 'xxxx.csv' WITH MAXBATCHSIZE=10
```

for example, I hava 2000 thousand recoreds csv file, after the above CQL is ran, there is 2000,000 records in cassandra, but the trigger is ran only 200 thousand  times.
why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because your data in the CSV file, has some same partition key.

> When importing data, the parent process reads from the input file(s) chunks with *CHUNKSIZE* rows and sends each chunk to a worker process. Each worker process then analyses a chunk for rows with common partition keys. If at least 2 rows with the same partition key are found, they are batched and sent to a replica that owns the partition. You can control the minimum number of rows with a new option, MINBATCHSIZE, but it is advisable to leave it set to 2. For rows that do not share any common partition key, they get batched with other rows whose partition key belong to a common replica. These rows are then split into batches of size MAXBATCHSIZE, currently 20 rows. These batches are sent to the replicas where the partitions are located. Batches are of type UNLOGGED in both cases.

base on:
 [link](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-features-in-cqlsh-copy)